# HTML email with tables nesting

Tags: html, html-table, nested, html-email

I'm writing some html code to make an html email.
I've done some research and I found that using old school html, such as tables etc is the best way to do this.

After all your help with previous problems (thank you!) I started working on the rest and making the layout easy to read on mobile devices, this is what I have now;

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
    <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; overflow-y:scroll; background-image: url(background.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: #dbdadb; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
    p { margin:0 0 10px 26px; line-height:1.2; width:320px;  font-size:0.9em;}
    .contact {margin-left:5px; margin-top:15px; width:170px; font-size:0.9em; text-align:center;}
    h1 { margin:0 0 10px 26px; line-height:1.2; width:320px;  font-size:1.1em; font-weight:normal;}
    img {outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display:block;}
    a img {border:none;}
    .headerwrapper {width:600px; background-color: #000000; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
    .header {text-align:center;}
    .wrapper {width:600px; background-color: #dbdadb; align:center;}
    .fixedwidth {width:600px !important;}
    .content {width:340px;}
    .icons {width:260px;}
    .devices {width:600px; height:310px;}
    .miniwrapper {width:600px;}
    .footer { background-image: url(http://i49.tinypic.com/54f2ac.png); text-align:center; line-height:1.2; width:320px;  font-size:0.9em;}
    .footermobile {display:none;}
    .actiemobile {display:none;}
    .iconwrapper {margin:0; line-height:1.2; font-size:0.9em;}
    .iconwrapper p {margin-left: 0px; margin-bottom:10px;}
    .headermobile {display:none;}
    .devicesmobile {display:none;}

    @media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; overflow-y:scroll; background-image: url(background.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: #dbdadb;}
    p { margin:0 0 10px 26px; line-height:1.2; width:350px;  font-size:0.9em;}
    .contactmobile {margin-left:50%; margin-top:15px; width:170px; font-size:1.1em; text-align:center; line-height:1.2em;}
    h1 { margin:0 0 10px 26px; line-height:1.2; width:320px;  font-size:1.1em; font-weight:normal;}
    .headerwrapper {width:320px; background-color: #000000; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
    .header {display:none;}
    .wrapper {width:100%; background-color: #dbdadb; align:center;}
    .fixedwidth {width:100% !important;}
    .content {width:320px; display:block;}
    .icons {width:260px; display:block;}
    .devices {display:none;}
    .miniwrapper {width:100%;}
    .footer {display:none;}
    .actie {display:none;}
    .footermobile {display:block; background-image: url(footermobile.png); text-align:center; line-height:1.2; width:320px; height:164px; font-size:0.9em;}
    .actiemobile {display:block;}
    .headermobile {display:block; text-align:center;}
    .devicesmobile {display:block;}
    }

    /* Client-specific Styles */
    #outlook a {padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */  
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line  spacing. */ 
    #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
    /* End reset */
    </style>
    <title>email template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="wrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" margin="0">
        <tbody class="headerwrapper">
                <tr class="header">
                    <td class="fixedwidth" colspan="2">
                        <img src="logo.png" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="devices" style="width:600px; height:300px;">
                    <td colspan="2">    
                        <img src="devices.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>   

                <tr class="headermobile">
                    <td class="fixedwidth" colspan="2">
                        <img src="logomobile.png" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="devicesmobile">
                    <td colspan="2">    
                        <img src="devicesmobile.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>   


        </tbody>
        <tr class="miniwrapper">
            <tr class="fixedwidth">
                <td class="content" align="left">
                    <h1>Werkt u al met apps?</h1>

<p>Het ontwikkelen van applicaties, oftewel apps, is namelijk booming! Steeds meer merken en 
bedrijven zien het gemak van een app in. Het is de ideale optie voor het versterken van uw merk, zowel extern als intern, of het opzetten van een geheel nieuw product. Ook de enorme groei in gebruik van mobiele apparaten zorgt er voor dat een sterk merk niet meer kan achter blijven.</p>

<p>Mocht u geïnteresseerd zijn in onze service, 
van op maat gemaakte applicaties en backend oplossingen, neem dan gerust contact met ons op.
U bent van harte welkom voor een kop koffie bij ons in de mediaBunker, tijdens een verkennend gesprek of een demonstratie van de 
mogelijkheden van mediaBunker als bedrijf.</p>

<p>Alvast bedankt en hopelijk tot ziens.</p>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="icons">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                No matter what device.<br>
                                We build natively.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <tbody class="iconwrapper">
                            <tr text-align="center">
                                <td><img src="apple.png"></td>
                                <td><p>Apple iOS is the operating<br>
                                    system that powers the <br>
                                    iPhone,  iPad and iPod touch.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="android.png"></td>
                                <td><p>With partners like Google,<br>
HTC and Motorola, Android is <br>
the fastest growing mobile OS.</p>
</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="windows.png"></td>
                                <td><p>Together Microsoft and Nokia<br>
support conventional users <br>
with Windows Phone.</p>
</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="html5.png"></td>
                                <td><p>Looking for other platforms<br>
like BlackBerry, Samsung <br>
Bada or HTML5 & CSS3?<br>
We can build it!</p>
</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </tr>
                    </table>        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="actie" colspan="2">
                <img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/11qi7pw.png">
            </td>
            <td class="actiemobile" colspan="2">
                <img src="actiemobile.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="footer" colspan="2">
            <table>
                <tr cellspace="0">
                    <td width="200px" text-align="center"><p class="contact">Suikersilo-West 23 <br> 1165 MP Halfweg</p></td>
                    <td width="200px" text-align="center"><p class="contact"><a href="tel:0031238200140">Tel +31 23 820 0140</a><br> <a href="mailto:info@mediabunker.com">info@mediabunker.com</a></p></td>
                    <td width="200px" text-align="center"><p class="contact"><a href="http://mediabunker.com">www.mediabunker.com</a><br> <a href="http://twitter.com/mediabunker">twitter.com/mediabunker</a></p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>

            <td class="footermobile" colspan="2">
            <table>
                <tr cellspace="0">
                    <td width="200px" text-align="center">
                        <p class="contactmobile">
                            Suikersilo-West 23<br>
                            1165 MP Halfweg<br>
                            <a href="tel:0031238200140">Tel +31 23 820 0140</a><br>
                            <a href="mailto:info@mediabunker.com">info@mediabunker.com</a><br>
                            <a href="http://mediabunker.com">www.mediabunker.com</a><br>
                            <a href="http://twitter.com/mediabunker">twitter.com/mediabunker</a><br>                        
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>  

</html>
```

I'm having some troubles making the layout work well on mobile devices too. I think I came up with a better solution though, use background images and place the other images (the devices, the banner etc) on top of that. That will probably solve that issue, right?

I have two other issues though; I can't get the icons td to go under the content when the page is viewed on a mobile device. I thought display block would do the trick but it doesn't... Also, there is this weird space on the right that came up when I added the icons table, it must conflict in some way, how do I fix this?

If it's any help, this was my previous question; [HTML email table nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033558/html-email-table-nesting/11034804#comment14452254_11034804)
And this is the online version; http://kellyvuijst.nl/email/email.html

Answer (score 0):

The `.icons` `td` is aligned hard left (when the viewport is less than 400px wide) because it has no `padding` or `margin` on it, whereas your other content (`h1`, `p`) has 26px `margin-right`.

You could address this by applying 26px of `padding-left` to .icons. This will make the left-hand edge of `.icons` align with the content above it.

**BUG #2, ATTEMPT 2:**

After reviewing the demo link you provided in your comment, I can see the problem you describe and its cause: your content is wider than its containing element.

You have set an explicit width for all paragraphs of 320px, which makes the `.iconwrapper` wider than it is supposed to be. I don't think you need to set a paragraph width, so just remove that CSS declaration.

(My suggestion when debugging these sort of layout issues is to use the developer tools in chrome to inspect your HTML elements and look how CSS styles are being applied. I find it really helps me to visualise my code, and see how it affects the layout.)

Comment: Thank you for solving the first problem, when I'm talking about the 'weird' space, I'm talking about the black and gray area (so the area without background) on the right, the layout kind of breaks there.

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't solve the problem, when I use your code out of fiddle (I'm using google chrome) the problems are still the same. An example here; http://kellyvuijst.nl/email/Untitled.html

Comment: Ah, now I really see. I thought the problems you described related specifically to viewing the email at narrow widths. The problem is pretty much the same: your content is wider than its container.

Comment: I'm just checking back to see if my suggestion resolved the right-hand gap issue?